# Showing integers with discrete topology homeomorphic (or not) to wedge sum of intervals

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I am trying to learn basic topology, and have just started wedge sums and Seifert-van Kampen. There are two exercises that I believe should be fairly simple but I am struggling to understand how to start them.

1 - Equip the integers $Z$ with the discrete topology and consider $CZ$ ($C$ presumably a constant). Prove it is homeomorphic to the wedge sum of a countable collection of unit intervals.

2 - Consider $D = \cup I_n$ for $I_n$ the line segment in $R^2$ connecting $(0, 1)$ to $(n, 0)$ equipped with the subspace topology. Show $CZ$ is not homeomorphic to $D$.

In both cases I think my trouble is picturing how the homeomorphism would occur. $CZ$ is simply a discrete collection of points { $ \dotsc, -2C, -C, 0, C, 2C, \dotsc $ } which when drawn is just a bunch of single points in $R$. The wedge sum in question 1 is a collection of unit intervals attached at a common base point (essentially a star graph), and $D$ in question 2 is a similar shape but with longer lines and a known basepoint 1 (again similar to a star graph with root vertex 1).

These are both meant to be simple warmup questions, and I'm doing okay on the actual questions so I assume I'm missing something obvious. Any help, answers or hints greatly appreciated.

Comment: $C\Bbb Z$ is the cone on the space $\Bbb Z$. $C$ is not a constant. Of course the later spaces you mention are uncountable so $\Bbb Z$ can't possibly be homeomorphic to them.

Comment: That changes everything, thanks. Will hopefully have no problems now.